# Nexus One stuck in loading screen - How to save application data? (ROOTED)

Tags: nexus-one, backup, adb, bootloader

I have my N1 rooted and after I installed BlackRose and change the partitions with password protection I wasn't able to start Android ever again. It show this screen:
[image]

I can access to the `adb shell`, and I can see all the private folders. So my question is

What folders/files do I need to backup to restore after the phone is fixed?

I know:
/data/data

anything else?

Comment: Is there any output to `adb logcat` while the phone is on that screen?  Can you still boot to Recovery or Bootloader?

Comment: Hi I can see the device on the adb list but no logcat nor application is opened.. I can start bootloader and fastboot. But because of the password thing I cannot do anything in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the locations you can try to back up:

```
/data/app/         --> location of APKs.
/data/app-private/ --> location of protected APKs.
/data/data/        --> location of app settings.
```

However, if you are trying to [install ICS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1366897) a complete wipe is most definitely required.

Generally, re-partitioning the internal memory should wipe its contents.  I would try manually re-flashing Recovery, wiping the device completely (system, data, cache, and dalvik cache) and re-flashing the ROM.  If you do manage to salvage any app data, I would highly recommend *not* restoring it on the new ROM, as that can lead to problems, especially if you are backing up to FAT/NTFS drive (Linux file permissions are lost.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll not install ICS.. I'm going to install again the same ROM I was using.. Thanks for your answer.